# É possível desenvolver com Codename One para o Windows Phone 8?

Tags: codename-one

Já é possível desenvolver aplicativo para Windows Phone 8 com Codename One? Ou somente a versão Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renan, sua resposta esta errada.
TODOS aplicativos que funcionam no Windows Phone 7 funcionam no Windows Phone 8.
Se você (como desenvolvedor), quiser, você pode optar por subir um pacote que será baixado pelos usuários de WP7.x e outro pacote que será baixado pelos usuários de WP8.x, mas se você subir um que da suporte ao WP7, ele tem suporte ao WP8.
Todos os games feitos com XNA funcionando tanto no WP7 quanto no WP8.
Lembrando que se você fizer um App com suporte ao WP7, ele não pode utilizar as APIs do WP8.

Ou seja, Junior, se você desenvolveu um App com Codename One para WP7, ele funciona no WP8, mas você não pode utilizar a SDK do WP8.

Comment: Obrigado!! Desculpe o incomodo 
Abraço!!
:D

Answer (score 2):

Mês passado saiu um build preliminar do Codename One com suporte ao WP8. [Maiores detalhes neste post no site do próprio.](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/04/windows-phone-8-and-the-state-of-7.html)

Atenção para diversos detalhes, como o fato de o XNA não ser suportado porque, de acordo com eles, o WP8 não suporta também; e aparentemente não é possível criar um binário que possa ser utilizado tanto no WP7 quanto no WP8.

Comment: Obrigado!!!! :D

Comment: Se a resposta lhe atendeu, marque ela como correta, assim ela sai da fila de Perguntas sem respostas